# python: can't call the function in the file from the webbrowser

Tags: python, csv, bottle

i want to make a RESTful web service using bottle framework in python. In it i've a CSV file which contains data of the lat and lan. I've to fetch that data and show it onto the browser everytime someone searches for a specific postcode from that file.
So, far i've done this.

```
 from bottle import route, run, request


@route('/')
def index():
    """ Display welcome & instruction messages """
    return "<p>Welcome to my extra simple bottle.py powered server!</p> \
           <p>The Web service can find a location from csv file \
           The way to invoke is :\
       <ul> \
              <li>http://localhost:8080/getlocation?postcode=xxxx</li>\
       </ul> \
       xxxx are the postcode you want to search."

@route('/getlocation/<postcode>')
def getlocation(postcode):
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('clinic_locations.csv', "r"), delimiter=",")
    #return{clinicname, latitude, longitude, email, state}
    for row in csv_file:
        if postcode == row[6]:
            return{row[3], row[8], row[9], row[7], row[5]}

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

in this i'm getting error on my browser

```
Sorry, the requested URL 'http://localhost:8080/getlocation?postcode=4000' caused an error:
```

i don't know where i'm wrong. 
Can anyone help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below has both the examples, dynamic parameter in the route [1] and query parameter[2]:

#### UPDATE

```
import json
from bottle import route, request, response, run, template, abort, error

@error(500)
@error(404)
@error(400)
def error_handler(error):
    try:
        error_details =  {"error_code": error.status_code, "message":    error.body}
    except:
        error_details =  {"error_code": 500, "message": error.exception}
    return json.dumps(error_details)

"""
    Example of try catch with bottle abort to handle
    custom error messages in the 'error_handler' above.
"""
@route("/")
def index():
try:
    raise Exception('A generic exception')
except Exception as ex:
    abort(500, ex.args[0])

@route("/greet/<name>")
def greet(name):
    return template("Greetings <b>{{name}}</b>", name=name)

@route("/greet")
def greet():
    if 'name' not in request.query:
        abort(400, "'name' parameter is missing...")    
    return template("Greetings <b>{{name}}</b>", name=request.query['name'])

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

To test above code :

- Except method : http://localhost:8080/
- First method  : http://localhost:8080/greet/StackOverflow
- Second method : http://localhost:8080/greet?name=StackOverflow

Comment: Thank you. Highly Appreciated.

Comment: please see the update..and  let me know if my answer helped you solve the issue?

Comment: This Helped me.
Thanks Sir.

Answer (score 1):

Your route is `/getlocation/<postcode>`, not `/getlocation?postcode=<postcode>`.

Comment: this didn't fixed my problem.

Comment: Sorry, the requested URL 'http://localhost:8080/getlocation?postcode=4000' caused an error:

Not found: '/getlocation'

Comment: did you restart the service after updating the code?

Comment: Yes, I do it everytime.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are doing this in the browser :

```
http://localhost:8080/getlocation?postcode=4000
```

Did you try:

```
http://localhost:8080/getlocation/4000
```

?

Comment: Same error again.
also, i need the url to be this format ***getlocation?postcode=xxxx***

Comment: I rewrite my code and your solution worked.
but again it is not in the format that i need it to be.

Comment: Maybe this will help ?: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#query-variables  From this it seems u only need @route('/getlocation')